# Separate each character in a string

Tags: c#

Hi everyone i am new member!
I'm having a problem. I transmit data between Arduino Due and C #.
C # receives a string a = "0.0.1.0.1.1100" from Arduino Due
I want to separate each character in the string a, I tried the Substring function but it was not effective. Is it something strange?

Comment: you really want each separate character? Or perhaps you mean you want all the individual numbers, without the dots? That sounds like a more useful requirement.  Can you tell us the exact required output? You probably want [string.Split()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8), by the sound of it. P.S. If you had a problem with the Substring method, it would make sense to show the code, show the output you wanted, and the real output you got. We can't guess what you might have done wrong - maybe substring is ok for you, but you just had a bug

Comment: If you literally want every character as seperate you can use something like this: `char[] charArr = a.ToCharArray();`

Comment: strings can be accessed like arrays. `a[0]` will give you the first character in the string, `a[1]` the second one and so forth. You can use `a.Split('.')` to get an array of all segments seperated by periods if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @ADyson my mean is get some number in string. Example 1100. can you help me? this is my code "string newInputData = InputData.Substring(10,4);" i used this, but it not return true

Comment: i used " string newInputData = InputData.Substring(10,4);" But it have error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string"

Comment: You should have said that before, it would have been a lot clearer. But to be honest I cannot see a problem with your code - it works as expected. here's a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EeT00n . The only thing I can see might be a problem is that in your question originally you defined your variable as `a` (i.e. `string a = ...`) and now you seem to be trying to do Substring on a variable called `InputData`...so maybe you just got confused about which variable to use?? I can't see any other reason why it would fail. If you work on the correct data (as per my demo) then there's no issue

Answer (score 2):

You can access strings each character like you access a character array's elements. So your strings first character is **a[0]**.
If you want to split the string along the dots, you can use **a.Split('.')** method that returns you a **string[]** array with the splitted elements.
I hope it helped.